# how to add implementation google mock setup in eclipse

Tags: c++, googlemock

1. Google mock example is created and built successfully in eclipse. 
   I have followed same procedure given in link 
   https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/ForDummies.md

C++ code is as followed;

```
Student.hpp

class Student
{
    private:
       string name;
       int roll_no;
       int marks;

    public:
       Student() {};
       virtual ~Student(){};
       virtual void getDetails() = 0;
       virtual void printDetails() = 0;
       virtual int getMarks() = 0;
};

mockStudent.hpp:
class MockStudent : public Student
{
    public:
       MOCK_METHOD0(getDetails, void());
       MOCK_METHOD0(printDetails, void());
       MOCK_METHOD0(getMarks, int(void));
};

main.cpp:

TEST(StudentTest, MarksTest)
{
  // This test is named "MarksTest", and belongs to the "StudentTest"
  // test case.
   MockStudent s2;

   EXPECT_CALL(s2, getMarks())
             .Times(AtLeast(1));
   cout << s2.getMarks();

}
GTEST_API_ int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    // The following line must be executed to initialize Google Mock
    // before running the tests.

    ::testing::InitGoogleMock(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

Above code is successfully compiled and run it.
Result is below:

```
[==========] Running 1 test from 1 test case.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 1 test from StudentTest
[ RUN      ] StudentTest.MarksTest
[       OK ] StudentTest.MarksTest (0 ms)    
[----------] 1 test from StudentTest (0 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 1 test from 1 test case ran. (0 ms total)
```

### [  PASSED  ] 1 test.

---

I have a doubt. Where can i implement my function definitions e.g getMarks() etc. 
I tried to add definitions in mockstudent.cpp(new file), but it was showing error "redefinition of functions". 
please pardon me if I am missing any concept.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you should go back to reading what exactly a mock is. What is your intention here? You use mocks instead of the implementation. Why do you want to add a definition now?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for [Setting Expectations](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/ForDummies.md#setting-expectations) and somthing like:

```
EXPECT_CALL(s2, getMarks())
.Times(AtLeast(1))
.WillOnce(Return(1));
```